# How reliable is the functionality Tap Target Spacing of Google Lighthouse?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, lighthouse

[Google Lighthouse](https://web.dev/measure) has a functionality called **Tap Target Spacing**, that checks if links has enough space to be clicked by a human finger without the likelihood of clicking on any other link nearer.

As described [here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-lighthouse-seo-audit-tool-now-measures-tap-target-spacing/297775/#close):

> “A minimum recommended touch target size is around 48 device
>   independent pixels on a site with a properly set mobile viewport. For
>   example, while an icon may only have a width and height of 24px, you
>   can use additional padding to bring the tap target size up to 48px.
>   The 48×48 pixel area corresponds to around 9mm, which is about the
>   size of a person’s finger pad area.”

To test the reliability of this tool, I built this simple html file that contains two links:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div>
<a href="#h" >Home</a>
<a href="#f" id="current">Fruit</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I test this html in [Google Lighthouse](https://web.dev/measure), I do not get the suggestion of **Tap targets are not sized appropriately
**, in this case my page have a **"good"** tap target spacing.

If I remove `<meta name="viewport"...` from my code and try again, I receive a suggestion to implement a viewport and to fix **Tap targets are not sized appropriately
**. In this case my page has a **bad** tap target spacing (and on that occasion the tool is right).

Now if I wrap my links with the `ul` and `li` tags, as shown in the code below:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#h" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#f" id="current">Fruit</a></li>
</ul>
```

I receive the suggestion **Tap targets are not sized appropriately**. But if we think more, without wrap tags like `ul` and `li`, lighthouse does not tell me anything (assuming you have no problem with the spaces between the links, while actually have).

So the Google Lighthouse has **LOW** reliable and leaves something to be desired in some tests?

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Lighthouse is a good starting point, but it doesn't tell the whole story. 
I also believe it comes with problems with lazy loaded elements and stuff below the fold.

All in all, you can you the report to start your investigation, but don't expect a report ready to go.